# segmentation fault after the allocation of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to create a linked list in my program. In my program the list is allocated on the heap with malloc(), than i try to visit it but i get a segmetation fault;

EDIT: i get the SIGSEGV at this line "while(!(node->nodeType == TYPE_END_LIST)){"

```
    struct dagNode *createList(int k);
    struct dagNode *newNodeXInterval(int type, int val);


    struct dagNode *createList(int k){
    struct dagNode *head, *node;
    printf("\nList %d = ", k);
    head = newNodeXInterval(TYPE_EDGE_OR_GAP, getVal(k,1));
    node = head;
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<LENGTH_OF(k); i++){
            node->next = newNodeXInterval(TYPE_XTEST, getRightPointOf(k,i));
            node = node->next;
            node->next = newNodeXInterval(TYPE_EDGE_OR_GAP, getVal(k,i+1));
            node = node->next;
            }     
    node = newNodeXInterval(TYPE_END_LIST, 0);
    node = head;     // i think that here there is the error
    printf("%d", node->val); i=0;
                    while(!(node->nodeType == TYPE_END_LIST)){
                        printf("%d ", i);
                        node = node->next;}
    return head;}


    struct dagNode *newNodeXInterval(int type, int val){
        struct dagNode *node = (struct dagNode *) malloc(sizeof(struct dagNode));
        if (type == TYPE_EDGE_OR_GAP){
        *node = (struct dagNode) {(val<0)? TYPE_GAP:TYPE_EDGE, val, NULL, NULL, NULL};
        }
        else{
        *node = (struct dagNode) {type, val, NULL, NULL, NULL};
        }
        return node;    }
```

The caller function would get the head of the list.

Comment: Please narrow this down -- in which line do you get the segmentation fault?

Comment: If you got a SEGV, presumably you can get a core and see _exactly_ where it died?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the problem is with the line

```
node = newNodeXInterval(TYPE_END_LIST, 0);
```

Before the assignement, `node` points to the last node in your linked list, and the previous node has its `next` pointer equal to `node`. After the assignement, `node` points to the newly created node with type `TYPE_END_LIST`, but the previous node has its `next` pointer unchanged (i.e. it still holds the original value of `node`). In other words, your newly created node is not a part of the list, and thus the condition `node->nodeType == TYPE_END_LIST` in the following `while()` loop will never evaluate to true, and you'll end up dereferencing a null pointer when you go past the end of the list. Changing the line to

```
node->next = newNodeXInterval(TYPE_END_LIST,0);
```

should fix the problem.